# jQuery LightSlider in Safari (WLAN) iPhone & PC Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, safari

on our company website, we are encountering some problems, with a jquery Lightslider, this slider isn't loading on safari on iPhone, Mac, and windows, but only if connected to the wireless network.

If we are connected to the mobile network there is no problem with the sliders, here is the error message we get on the console:

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...$self.lightSlider...')
    (anonyme Funktion) (unternehmen:151)
    each (jquery.min.js:2:14548)
    each (jquery.min.js:2:11222)
    (anonyme Funktion) (unternehmen:145)
    l (jquery.min.js:2:17002)
    fireWith (jquery.min.js:2:17785)
    ready (jquery.min.js:2:12516)
    A (jquery.min.js:2:9915)
```

with best regards and thanks in advance for your clues and solutions